# Web.config File Removes .html extension from URL but site is not accessible from plain URL

Tags: html, url, web-config

I'm currently using the following Web.config file which successfuly removes the .html extension from the URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="Redirecting .html ext" />
                <remove name="Hide .html ext" />
                <rule name="Hide .html ext" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirecting .html ext" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*).html" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*)\.html$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you try to access the site through a link with slash name of page like this:
https://digitalspark.solutions/home
the site is accessible, but if you try the plain link, like this:
https://digitalspark.solutions/
it doesn't work.
Can someone help me with this please?